# How to back to last step in microsoft sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I just deleted lots of data by mistake:

```
DELETE
FROM [stock_database].[dbo].[spy1]
WHERE CONVERT(time, datetime) >= '2020-10-06';
```

Is there anyway I can back to last step to cancel this delete?

Comment: If it is inside a transaction, you can roll-back the transaction.

Comment: Can you give more detail about How to use it?

Comment: If you didn't explicitly define a transaction by typing BEGIN TRANSACTION then you didn't use a transaction.  Unfortunately you'll need to restore a database backup to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

A way to recover the deleted rows is to use the transaction log.
This is a very complicated approach...
Let us see whats is in the transaction log, by executing this query :

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL, NULL);
```

As you see a majority of data are in and hex format.

Some vendors give some tools to automate such a recovery. As an example Apex log exlorer "Apex log exlorer" does it...
https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-log.aspx